# Premium result with BlackProcess not in line with online engines

Tags: programming, quantlib, black76

I'm trying to implement BlackProcess with Quantlib (in C#) and the result I get for NPV() is not inline with some resources I can find online. Here is my code:

```
var underlyingH = new Handle<Quote>(new SimpleQuote(27.77));
var underlierVolatility = 0.22;
var dayCounter = new Actual365Fixed();
var settlementDate= DateTime.UtcNow;

var flatTermStructure = new Handle<YieldTermStructure>(new FlatForward(settlementDate, 0.001, dayCounter));
var flatVolTs = new Handle<BlackVolTermStructure>(new BlackConstantVol(settlementDate, calendar, underlierVolatility, dayCounter ));
var computationEngine = new BlackProcess(underlyingH, flatTermStructure, flatVolTs);

// Option
var payoff = new PlainVanillaPayoff(type, (double)option.Instrument.Strike);
var europeanOption = new VanillaOption(payoff, new EuropeanExercise(option.Instrument.Expiry.DateTime));

// Black-76 on european option
europeanOption.setPricingEngine(new AnalyticEuropeanEngine(computationEngine));
```

The resources I use to compare my result are:
http://lombok.demon.co.uk/financialTap/options/bond/shortterm
https://commoditymodels.files.wordpress.com/2012/07/black-76-calculator.xls

My question is: What can create a difference in NPV (1-2% diff) in the result I get form QuantLib according to vanilla engines we can find online?

I suspect a mistake in the way I use the different "parameters" like:

- FlatForward
- BlackConstantVol
- Actual365 calendar

I admit having expected very (very) close results.

Comment: I would expect very close results, too. What inputs did you give to the online calculators?

Comment: Same as hard coded in code above: Strike Put26, ImplVol 22%, Spot 27.77. My main lead is about the Time to Maturity. I take the one `dayCounter` gives me. But the question is: how does BlackProcess handle date from `flatVolTs` and `flatTermStructure`? Is there some +1 or -1 here and there in QuantLib by default?

Comment: The code doesn't show today and expiry; what were they? Anyway, the process uses the day counter too, with no +1 or -1.  One thing: the first resource you link asks for the forward price, not the spot. Did you correct for that? How?

Comment: I did not notice this "forward" thing. No actually, I use the same Spot price in both cases. You definitely have something here. How does that work or is being fixed? FYI: the input I have in my system is the spot price of a future Commodity taken from Bloomberg.

Comment: I suspect bad wording on the first resource. Using the label "forward" looks wrong. The second resource (excel file) gives the same result as the first one with Spot price.

Comment: What are your today and expiry, and what is the time to maturity you're passing to the calculator?

Comment: BlackProcess with: Put26, Spot 27.25, Today 2016-08-03 11:40 (UTC), Expiry 2016-12-08 00:00 (UTC) hence TTM is 0.3439, ImpVol is 23.49%, RiskFree rate 0.1%. QuantLib gives NPV=0.9286, Website (1st resource) gives NPV=0.9209, excel file (2nd resource) gives NPV=0.9207. As you can see, my QuantLib result is quite off. Hope it helps. Thanks a lot.

Comment: According to act/365, TTM from August 3rd to December 8th is 0.3479 (not 0.3439) which in your 1st resource gives 0.9287, so basically the same as QuantLib.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your last comment gave me a lead on where my issue is. I now have the same result as you do. The problem comes from my misunderstanding of the `Actual365.yearFraction(d1, d2)`. I use it for debug and get the TTM (hence my wrong number in the previous comment). I guess the question is: why does the call to `yearFraction(2016-08-03Z11:40, 2016-12-08Z00:00)` equals `0.3439` when the TTM seems to be `0.3479` in the inner computation of BlackProcess?

Comment: Adding to my comment: it seems that calling yearFraction directly takes the `hour` an `minute` part of the date into account. But the inner wiring of Quantlib, the `yearFraction` accuracy is on the day. `0.3479` is the value if the valuation date does not have the `11h40` part. Why is that? How can we ensure the time precision used in the computation is to the minute/second, not day? Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reframing this as an answer for future reference.

First of all, what I'm writing here applies to the C++ version of QuantLib and its C# wrappers generated by SWIG; if you're using the QLNet native C# port, I've no idea how that works.

By default, QuantLib works at a day resolution and will ignore the hour while calculating TTM, which caused the difference between your calculations and the QuantLib result.  (By the way, it's now quite clear to me how you got the TTM including the hour by calling the `yearFraction` method on the day counter; that, too, should have worked at day resolution.)

Since version 1.7, it is possible to compile QuantLib so that it takes the time of day into account (the feature is not enabled by default because it causes some loss of performance). On Windows, uncomment the line

```
//#    define QL_HIGH_RESOLUTION_DATE
```

and recompile both QuantLib and the C# module.  On other systems, run

```
./configure --enable-intraday
```

and recompile the whole thing. Again, this applies to the C++ version and the C# wrappers generated by SWIG.